# How to delete pointers from vector pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I use [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) parser generator  that has `union` type for return type productions.

```
union {
    std::vector<std::string*> *vecStrPtr;
    // double num; ...
};
```

how delete pointer from vector pointer;

```
    auto v = new std::vector<std::string*>();
 //....
    v->push_back(new std::string("text"));
//...
    delete v[0];
```

error: type `'class std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*>'` argument given to 'delete', expected pointer `delete v[0];`

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer to the `vector` first: `(*v)[0]`. Although why are you `new`ing all over the place anyway? Doesn't seem to be any reason for it.

Comment: Why do you need to use pointer?

Comment: Why are you using `new` and `delete` at all? That's not necessary, c++ isn't java.

Comment: `new` is obsolete, don't use it.

Comment: Why do you say that new is obsolete ??? That stupid !

Comment: Did you forget that `v` was a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

When you do just `v[0]` you get the vector because `v` is a pointer and then you need to get value from that vector. You can do it by adding another array access. So working code would look like `delete v[0][0];`. But two array accesses can be confusing when you are accessing value from one dimension array (vector).

Another way to get vector from pointer `v` is to dereference it. Code would look like `(*v)[0]`. It's more clear accessing the value. With `(*v)` you will get the vector and then the array access is to access the value from vector.

To remove value from vector use method `erase`. For more information about that method look at this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/). Code example would look like:

```
auto v = new std::vector<std::string*>();
//....
v->push_back(new std::string("text"));
//...
delete (*v)[0];
v->erase(v->begin());
```

Better is to write code without keyword new. With that rule you will get less memory leaks. It makes your developing easier. But in some cases you can't use it. Your code example modified by that rule would look like:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back(std::string("text"));

//here is how to get pointers from it
std::string* ptrToElement = &(v[0]);
std::vector<std::string>* ptrToVector = &v;
```

Comment: Thank you, I noticed that too, but just after post... I hope my edited post is better.

Comment: By the way `v[0]` isn't problem, it just takes value from pointed memory with zero offset. I had more other mistakes in my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to free one item is:

```
delete (*v)[index];
v->erase(b->begin()+index);
```

However, You should make sure that you really want to allocate a vector in the free store. It seems usually so wrong.

P.S. As @Dahn mentioned, Those two instructions should be atomic.

Comment: @Danh why? How would you retrieve the pointer to be `delete`d if you erased it first ?

Comment: @Danh I could think of any reason ?? enlight me please?

Comment: @Danh interesting.. thanks for mentioning that.. Maybe typical implementation should be atomic for those two instructions

Comment: @Danh even with the temporary variable, another thread could load the pointer's value from the vector, be preempted, then you erase & delete the object from under its feet. Whatever you do, you *have* to synchronize that, and then the order of erasure and deletion is irrelevant. In any case, there's no mention of multithreading in this question.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, forgot that, thanks. We need to synchronize it instead of reorder it